# Javascript array format for charts

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
A =[1990,1991,....]
B=[a,b,c,d,e,f,...]
```

I want the resultant array in this format

```
Resultant=[{
                name: 1990,
                data: [a,b,c]

            },{
                name: 1991,
                data: [d,e,f]

            },...
           ]
```

Please help me how will I make it using for loops?

Comment: So you want to split B every 3 items?

Comment: See here for a start: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: not spliting the length of array A and will be known and based on that using for loop we have to make it.

Comment: It is little bit tricky can you help me??

Comment: Not working dude. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var b= ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var result = [1990,1991].map(function(n){ return { name:n, data: b.splice(0,3)} });
```

Comment: This is working but data value are not getting correctly it is getting 0 values.

Comment: It is partially working thank you for the logic. But in data the values are not correctly getting. can you rectify it?

Comment: data is an array it is returning an array I think we all did it that way

Comment: Image added please help me.

Comment: In highcharts x axis is coming but y axis is not showing, its getting zero values

Answer (score 0):

This will format data with `Array.prototype.map`, based on your (rather vague) requirement:

```
var A = [1990,1991];
var B = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var formatted = A.map(function (name, i) {
    return {
        name: name,
        data: B.slice(i*3, i*3+3)
    }
});

/*[
    {
        "name": 1990,
        "data": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": 1991,
        "data": [
            "d",
            "e",
            "f"
        ]
    }
]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for each in A, you want data to store 3 elements of B. I've stuck with your requirement of using for loops.

```
var Resultant = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   var data = [];
   for (var j = 0; j < 3, B.length > 0; j++) {
       data.push(B.shift());
   }

   Resultant.push({name: A[i], 'data': data});
}
```

Comment: Tried but data values not getting correctly. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/s5zdD/  <-- see jsfiddle to show

```
A =[1990,1991,1992];
B=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];

var Resultant = jQuery.map(A, function(i,v){
// if no jQuery use:
// var Resultant = A.map(function(i,v){
    return {
        'name':A[v],
        'data': B.splice(0,3)
    }
})

console.log(Resultant);
```